# iTerm terminal emulation is weird

Tags: macos, terminal, tmux, iterm2, macos-highsierra

Recently, I switched to iTerm because a lot of people recommends it, but it behaves quite weirdly. It does not automatically enter "alternate screen mode" if less/man/similar commands are run, and it seems like commands cannot overwrite contents on the screen. It seems like using tmux solves some of the issue, but I can't get tmux scrolling to work. Am I doing something wrong? Video: https://youtu.be/mbbEViOS5Kg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following troubleshooting instructions from Nachman (https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/9287),I found that I selected "ansi" as the terminal type for whatever reason I forget. Changing it back to "xterm-256" solves the problem.